# LISA plot in tmap - wrong palette

Tags: tmap, ggplot

I'm trying to make a LISA plot (checking income concentration by census tract in a rural region in Spain) in `{tmap}`and the palette keeps coming out wrong. I can do it without problem in `{ggplot2}`, though. The problem is that it does not match the colour to the quadrant but apparently it assigns a colour to each variable at random.

This is what the data looks like.

```r
> tibble(head(select(lisaregion, CUSEC, `renta media`, Ii, Z.Ii, `Pr(z > 0)`, quadrant, `geometry`)))
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  CUSEC      `renta media`       Ii   Z.Ii `Pr(z > 0)` quadrant                                                                                   geometry
  <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>                                                                            <MULTIPOLYGON [m]>
1 3901701001         11635  0.865   2.01        0.0223 No significativo (((428477.9 4765900, 428481.9 4765820, 428447.9 4765805, 428355.9 4765816, 428207~
2 3902701001         13343 -0.00745 0.0963      0.462  Alto-Bajo        (((406623.4 4760258, 406635.8 4760188, 406639.8 4760023, 406577.9 4759916, 406575~
3 3902701002         12971  0.0883  0.732       0.232  No significativo (((412172.7 4765268, 412062.7 4764958, 411857.7 4764711, 411693.7 4764207, 411693~
4 3902701003         12481  0.165   0.391       0.348  No significativo (((407127.6 4759863, 406906.8 4759193, 406621.7 4758623, 406336.7 4758404, 406029~
5 3902701004         13752  0.0530  0.415       0.339  No significativo (((410646.7 4765601, 410568.2 4765310, 410217.4 4764739, 409647.4 4764279, 408880~
6 3903201001         15307  1.16    1.78        0.0374 Alto-Alto        (((403534.4 4772110, 403432.4 4769973, 403315.2 4769204, 403212.6 4766659, 402736~
```

The column "quadrant" has the LISA categories.

Here's the code I'm using for each version and the results.

```r
# using tmap - BAD
tm_shape(lisaregion) +
  tm_polygons(col = "quadrant", 
              breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
              palette=  c("white","red","blue",rgb(0,0,1,alpha=0.4),rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.4)), 
              labels = c("No significativo", "Alto-Alto","Bajo-Bajo","Bajo-Alto","Alto-Bajo"), title="")+
  tm_legend(text.size = 1)  +
  tm_shape(reinosa_silueta) + 
  tm_borders(lwd = 2, col = "black") + 
  tm_add_legend(type = "fill",
                labels = c("Reinosa"),
                border.col = "black",
                lwd= 3,
                col = NA) + 
  tm_scale_bar() +
  tm_compass() + 
  tm_credits("Fuente: INE, Colaboradores de OpenStreetMap",
             bg.color = "white",
             bg.alpha = 0.7) + 
  tm_layout(main.title = "Concentración de la renta por\nsecciones censales 2019",
            fontfamily = "Open Sans",
            legend.outside = TRUE,
            legend.format = list(text.separator = "-"))
```

[image]

```
# using ggplot - GOOD
# I don't include the basemap or the central polygon - just for the example
colors <- c("red", "blue",  rgb(0,0,1,alpha=0.4), rgb(1,0,0,alpha=0.4), "white")
names(colors) <- c("Alto-Alto", "Bajo-Bajo", "Bajo-Alto", "Alto-Bajo", "No significativo")

ggplot(data = lisaregion) + 
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = quadrant)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors) + 
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = "Concentración de la renta por\nsecciones censales 2019",
       caption = "Fuente: INE",
       fill = NULL) + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Open Sans"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

[image]

As you can see, the colour pattern is the same in both maps but the first one assigns the wrong colours to each polygon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to convert `quadrant` to `factor` and assign the levels in the order you want them to appear. This is in fact the default behaviour of `ggplot2`. See how it can be done on the next reprex:

```r
library(mapSpain)

# Mock your data
lisaregion <- esp_get_munic(region = "Cantabria")

reinosa_silueta <- esp_get_munic(munic = "^Reinosa", region = "Cantabria")

labels <- c(
  "No significativo", "Alto-Alto",
  "Alto-Bajo", "Bajo-Alto", "Bajo-Bajo"
)

quadrant <- sample(labels, nrow(lisaregion), replace = TRUE)


lisaregion$quadrant <- quadrant
head(lisaregion)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 8 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -4.26761 ymin: 43.12205 xmax: -3.35883 ymax: 43.50824
#> Geodetic CRS:  ETRS89
#>      codauto ine.ccaa.name cpro ine.prov.name cmun             name LAU_CODE
#> 5811      06     Cantabria   39     Cantabria  001 Alfoz de Lloredo    39001
#> 5799      06     Cantabria   39     Cantabria  002          Ampuero    39002
#> 5836      06     Cantabria   39     Cantabria  003          Anievas    39003
#> 5803      06     Cantabria   39     Cantabria  004  Arenas de Iguña    39004
#> 5804      06     Cantabria   39     Cantabria  005          Argoños    39005
#> 5781      06     Cantabria   39     Cantabria  006          Arnuero    39006
#>                            geometry         quadrant
#> 5811 POLYGON ((-4.16939 43.34409...        Alto-Alto
#> 5799 POLYGON ((-3.47351 43.30369...        Alto-Bajo
#> 5836 POLYGON ((-4.01932 43.22706... No significativo
#> 5803 POLYGON ((-3.95181 43.14985...        Alto-Alto
#> 5804 POLYGON ((-3.51452 43.46043...        Alto-Bajo
#> 5781 POLYGON ((-3.54251 43.49319...        Bajo-Bajo

# Solution: convert quadrant to factor and arrange levels

lisaregion$quadrant <- factor(lisaregion$quadrant,
  levels = c(
    "Alto-Alto", "Bajo-Bajo", "Bajo-Alto", "Alto-Bajo",
    "No significativo"
  )
)

colors <- c(
  "red", "blue", rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha = 0.4),
  rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.4), "white"
)

# The map with tmap
library(tmap)


tm_shape(lisaregion) +
  tm_polygons(
    col = "quadrant",
    palette = colors,
    title = ""
  ) +
  tm_legend(text.size = 1) +
  tm_shape(reinosa_silueta) +
  tm_borders(lwd = 2, col = "green") +
  tm_add_legend(
    type = "fill",
    labels = c("Reinosa"),
    border.col = "black",
    lwd = 3,
    col = NA
  ) +
  tm_scale_bar() +
  tm_compass() +
  tm_credits("Fuente: INE, Colaboradores de OpenStreetMap",
    bg.color = "white",
    bg.alpha = 0.7
  ) +
  tm_layout(
    main.title = "Concentración de la renta por\nsecciones censales 2019",
    fontfamily = "Open Sans",
    legend.outside = TRUE,
    legend.format = list(text.separator = "-")
  )
#> Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database

#> Warning in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, :
#> font family not found in Windows font database
```

[image]

```r
# Same with ggplot
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)


ggplot(data = lisaregion) +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = quadrant)) +
  geom_sf(data = reinosa_silueta, fill = NA, color = "green") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "bl") +
  annotation_scale(location = "br") +
  labs(
    title = "Concentración de la renta por\nsecciones censales 2019",
    caption = "Fuente: INE, Colaboradores de OpenStreetMap",
    fill = NULL
  ) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>